# Search the post using get_search_form()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fetch the post based on the search of the keyword , I have used the get_search_form() also created the **searchform.php** in my root folder of the theme (Child theme).

find my files below

**file1.php**

```
<article class="blogBanner">
        <div class="caption">
            <h1>All About Travel, Food &amp; Holidays</h1>
            <h4>Experience the Change</h4>
            <div class="field">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>     
            </div>
        </div>
</article>
```

**searchform.php** (this file is in the root folder of child theme)

```
<form role="search" name="main-search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" name="s" placeholder="" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

So whenever I search for the posts with any keyword from the form(form is from searchform.php) it shows all the posts irrespective of the keyword searched.

Comment: WordPress search will work with title and content which make it sometime irrelevant search results. If you want some specific search result then i think you should have a custom search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specific search result you can flow these steps:-
step:-1. create a php  template file in your theme->template parts->yourtemplatename.php
step:2- Go to your theme->search.php and make change like
template-parts/content', 'search' to template-parts/product', 'yourtemplatename'
your yourtemplatename.php shoud be your custome query like below:-

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$title = $_GET['s'];
$myposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s' AND post_type LIKE 'post'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $title ) .'%') );
foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) 
{
    $posty = get_post( $mypost );
?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php echo $posty->post_title;
echo"<br>";
?></a>
<?php }?>
```